# Check to see if AD Group is empty

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a way to first check if the AD group is empty and if so, write to the CSV file something like "$GroupName + is empty." I imagine this will be in a IF-THEN construct, but note sure where to place it in my code below or the syntax. Thank you for your help.

```
#Script will export group members from the imported list of groups
#Import the AD Module necessary for the script to run
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#specify the file that contains group names
$groups = Get-Content C:\temp\grouplist.txt
$UserProperties = 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'Name'

$resultsarray =@()

foreach ($group in $groups){

    $resultsarray += Get-ADGroupMember -Id $group -Server Server01.domain.com | Get-ADUser -Properties $UserProperties | select (@{n='FirstName';e={$_.GivenName}},
    @{n='LastName';e={$_.Surname}},'Name',@{e={$group};Label="GroupName"})

}
$resultsarray | Export-csv -path C:\temp\Groups_$(get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd).csv -NTI
```

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` can return user, computer or group objects. With "_check if the AD group is empty_" you apparently mean there are no **users** in the group? What if there are groups in the group, but no direct user objects. Is that empty for you?

Comment: The groups could have either users or other groups. One group in particular typically has nothing in it, but could have users or groups added for short periods. So, each day this script runs and will report out the group membership. If the group is empty, which it usually is, I just want the script to report that. But, if the group has members, then report the members (but not recursive - I don't need the membership of the other groups).

Comment: Group and User objects have different properties. There is no `GivenName` on a group for instance.. Please edit your question and tell us what properties you want in the output for groups.

Comment: If the groups in the list have users, then list the user properties (GivenName, Surname, Name). If there is a nested group, I just want the Group name.

Comment: So you do want to recurse.. Maybe have a look at [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-nested-group-15f725f2)

Comment: No, not recursive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some comments, I think I now understand the question as to when it should be empty or not.
Because the `Get-ADGroupMember` can return objects of type 'user', 'group' or 'computer', the code needs to handle that and output different results depending on the `objectClass` of each member.
However, since you want the result as CSV file, you need to take care all objects return the same structured object.
The following should do what you ask for:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#specify the file that contains group names
$groups = Get-Content C:\temp\grouplist.txt
$UserProperties = 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'Name'

# loop through the groups and collect group member info in a variable '$result'
$result = foreach ($group in $groups){
    # get all members of the group and force it to be an array
    $groupMembers = @(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Server 'Server01.domain.com')
    if ($groupMembers.Count) {
        foreach ($member in $groupMembers) {
            switch ($member.objectClass) {
                'user' {
                    # emit an object with the following user properties
                    $member | Get-ADUser -Properties $UserProperties | 
                              Select-Object @{Name = 'FirstName'; Expression = {$_.GivenName}},
                                            @{Name = 'LastName'; Expression = {$_.Surname}},
                                            'Name',
                                            @{Name = 'MemberType'; Expression = {$member.objectClass}},
                                            @{Name = 'GroupName'; Expression = {$group}},
                                            @{Name = 'GroupIsEmpty'; Expression = {$false}}
                }
                default {
                    # for other objects like groups or computers, keep the same structure
                    # and only fill in the Name, MemberType and GroupName properties
                    '' | Select-Object 'FirstName','LastName',
                                        @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = {$member.Name}},
                                        @{Name = 'MemberType'; Expression = {$member.objectClass}},
                                        @{Name = 'GroupName'; Expression = {$group}},
                                        @{Name = 'GroupIsEmpty'; Expression = {$false}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        # the group is empty. Again: keep the same structure as above
        '' | Select-Object 'FirstName','LastName','Name','MemberType',
                            @{Name = 'GroupName'; Expression = {$group}}, 
                            @{Name = 'GroupIsEmpty'; Expression = {$true}}
    }
}

$outFile = 'C:\temp\Groups_{0:yyyy-MM-dd}.csv' -f (Get-Date)
$result | Export-csv -path $outFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

<sup>Note: in this case you do not even need to use the `-Properties` parameter on the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet, since all the properties you want (`$UserProperties = 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'Name'`) are returned by default</sup>

Comment: works nicely. thanks!! I see the logic now, so great help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out but it could be something like

```
#Script will export group members from the imported list of groups
#Import the AD Module necessary for the script to run
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#specify the file that contains group names
$groups = Get-Content C:\temp\grouplist.txt
$UserProperties = 'GivenName', 'Surname', 'Name'

$resultsarray =@()

foreach ($group in $groups){

    $result = Get-ADGroupMember -Id $group -Server Server01.domain.com | Get-ADUser -Properties $UserProperties | select (@{n='FirstName';e={$_.GivenName}},
    @{n='LastName';e={$_.Surname}},'Name',@{e={$group};Label="GroupName"})
    $resultsarray += if ($result) {$result} else {"$($group) is empty"}

}
$resultsarray | Export-csv -path C:\temp\Groups_$(get-date -Format yyyy-MM-dd).csv -NTI
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It prints a blank line in the CSV file where the group would have been.

Comment: Please could you try replacing this line:
    *$resultsarray += if ($result) {$result} else {"$($group) is empty"}*
first with
    *$resultsarray += if ($null -eq $result) {$result} else {"$($group) is empty"}* 
and if that doesn't work, with
    *$resultsarray += if ($result -eq "") {$result} else {"$($group) is empty"}*
and finally with 
    *$results\array += if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result)) {$result} else {"$($group) is empty"}*

Comment: That last line should read 
    *$resultsarray += if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($result)) {$result} else {"$($group) is empty"}*

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those work. It produces some interesting results though. I get a count of users I think. It literally exports a few lines with numbers in them. "length 39, 46, 45"